# Clear Contents of Rows Depending on Cell Range

Tags: vba, excel

Data layout: A3 onwards to A(no specific last row) is referred to as under Name Manager as =PeriodPrev.
=PeriodPrev is a label that I have used to mark the data. =PeriodCurr label starts after the last populated row for PeriodPrev. 
The remaining data for PeriodPrev and PeriodCurr lay under column E to W.

Code: How to I create a clear contents of data in Columns A and E to W for data belonging to =PeriodPrev in Column A?
I've tried the following code but it does not completely serves the purpose above. "If c.Value = "PeriodPrev" Then" returns error 13. "If c.Value = Range("PeriodPrev") Then" return error 1004.

```
Sub BYe()
'The following code is attached to the "Clear" button which deletes Previous Period data

    Dim c As Range

    Dim LastRow As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet


    ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In Range("A3:A" & LastRow)
        If c.Value = "PeriodPrev" Then
       ' If c.Value = Range("PeriodPrev") Then
        c.EntireRow.ClearContents
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  Intersect

```
If Not Application.Intersect(c, Range(yourLabel)) Is Nothing Then
```

Let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There were a few thing wrong with that code. I've tried to address some of the problems with comments

```
Sub BYe()
    'The following code is attached to the "Clear" button which deletes Previous Period data
    Dim c As Range, lastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    'you need to SET a range or worksheet object  
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'you've Set ws, might as well use it
    With ws
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each c In .Range("A3:A" & lastRow)
            'the Intersect determines if c is within PeriodPrev
            If Not Intersect(c, .Range("PeriodPrev")) Is Nothing Then
                'this clears columns A and E:W on the same row as c.
                .Range(.Cells(c.Row, "A"), .Cells(c.Row, "E").Resize(1, 19)).ClearContents
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

The following should perform the same action without the loop.

```
Sub BYe2()
    'The following code is attached to the "Clear" button which deletes Previous Period data
    Dim lastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lastRow = .Range("PeriodPrev").Rows(.Range("PeriodPrev").Rows.Count).Row
        .Range("A3:A" & lastRow & ",E3:W" & lastRow).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get error 1004 for this line : "lastRow = .Range(PeriodPrev).Rows(.Range(PeriodPrev).Rows.count).Row"

Comment: My apologies. The PeriodPrev should have been quoted.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, it does not work either. I tried the following code but the same 1004 error still appeared on the lastrow =...etc line.                     'Sub BYe2()


Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
        
    
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_LE")
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macros").Range("PeriodPrev")

With ws
    lastRow = .Range("PeriodPrev").Rows(.Range("PeriodPrev").Rows.count).Row
    .Range("A3:A" & lastRow & ",E3:W" & lastRow).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub

Comment: I get error 1004 under this line: If Not Intersect(c, .Range("PeriodPrev")) Is Nothing Then

Comment: That would indicate a problem with the named range. Either the name is wrong or the range is wrong. I'm sorry but I have no way to tell; all I can relate is that the code worked in my sample workbook.

Comment: The range (periodprev) has been defined in the macros sheet cell D17.I've written a code to make PeriodPrev to appear in the active sheet. The code above is meant to delete cells that have been defined as PeriodPrev. However, it is not recognising it under column A. In fact it thinks that it does not appear in the active sheet at all.

Comment: This worked:                                                                                               Sub ClearContentsofPrevPeriod()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim blah As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_LE")
Set blah = Range("PeriodPrev")

Sheets("Data_LE").Activate

With ws
    lastRow = .Range(blah).Rows(.Range(blah).Rows.count).Row
    Range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",B2:W" & lastRow).ClearContents
    End With
   
End Sub